# jVectorMap change SVG stroke color

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jvectormap

Using jVectorMap on a site and would like to change the stroke color of state borders within the USA map. Have tried inserting a stroke color within each states coords within the path to no avail.

Has anyone been able to do such thing?

Answer (score 11):

Appears you can add the stroke in the stylesheet.

```
.jvectormap-region {
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't achieve this easily now without modifying the code of the jVectorMap.

Comment: im not too worried about getting into the code just need a little direction.

Comment: Take a look on how `setColors` and `setFill` methods implemented. You need to replace `fill` with `stroke`.

Comment: I believe now the code has changed. I'm using version 1.2.2. Can you tell me what I can do to set border color of region? CSS is working only in Chrome but not in IE (IE 9).

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following code around line 123 of jquery.vector-map.js:

```
node.setAttribute('d', config.path);
node.setAttribute('stroke', '#000000'); // Whatever color you like!
node.setFill = function(color)...
```

Greetings!

Another question: my VML Fallback doesn't seem to work. The path coordinates are from an SVG created by Adobe Illustrator. Has anyone the same problem or can give me a solution which programm to use to create the path data?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and thanks for contributing your answer to this question! If you have a question of your own to ask, you should ask a new, separate question, rather than placing it in this answer. If it lives here, no one will see it. Also, answers should contain only answers.